# LIVE pricing feed supplied by another site in magento

Tags: xml, magento, feed

We are working on magento. but here we have to get product prices from another website using xml feed.

actually we are working on jewellery website using magento. we are adding products from backend. but gold prices are ups and down its depends upon market value. so how can i assign price to products. any sugguestions?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what's being asked here. What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: You have got the any solution muralikalpana??

Answer (score 1):

you can use the magento api to update prices based on gold price. you would

get the current price of the item and calculate the new price based on gold.

say you have an item with a price of $100, and that price was based on gold @ $1,200 per ounce. now gold is at $1,300 per ounce

so you would do 1300/1200 = 1.083333333
1.083333333 * 100 = 108.3333333

so your new price would be $108.33